# How to use a function from another file in Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am trying to create a .js file in my electron project that contains functions I create. I have tried numerous methods to try and import my .js file into another to use it's functions. Does the *require* method only work in the main.js file or can it be used in any .js file that is in the project?

```
// utilities.js
arraySearch (inputArray, inputName)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < inputArray.buttons.length; i++)
    {
        if (inputArray.buttons[i].name === inputName)
        {
            return inputArray.buttons[i];
        }
    }
}

module.exports = arraySearch;
```

```
// file I want to import in
const toolset = require('./utilities.js');
```

The error I am receiving is ***Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined***

**EDIT:** Another solution I tried was using the import method but I got the error ***Cannot use import outside a module***

Comment: Searching for "electron" and the error message yields _many_ results, have you tried any solutions?

Comment: Yes i have tried a few solutions, none of them are working

Comment: To prevent duplicate suggestions it'd be a good idea to edit your question with what you've already tried.

Comment: Sure I have updated the post with another common solution I tried

Comment: `webPreferences` are options to [BrowserWindow](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#new-browserwindowoptions). Look for `nodeIntegration`. `enableRemoteModule` and `contextIsolation` meaning.

Comment: Thank you, that solved my issues